# Como agregar varios datos de una estructura en una lista C++

Tags: lista

El problema esta en que quiero agregar varios tipos de datos en una lista pero solo he conseguido que inserte un solo dato por lista, y quisiera saber como muestro todos esos datos de la lista por pantalla, al inicio solo pude hacerlo con la variable codigo pero al insertar los otros datos se me cae el programa.
En esta sección quiero agregar mas datos en la estructura

```
    struct Pasajes{
    int codigo;
    char cliente[20];//Estos quisiera que aparezcan en la lista
    char destino[20];//Estos quisiera que aparezcan en la lista
    struct Pasajes *ptrSig;
};

typedef struct Pasajes *lista, *nodo;

int Menu();
nodo CrearNodo(void);
void InsertarPasaje(lista *Inicio, lista *Fin);
void RecorrerLista(lista Inicio);
void BuscarPasaje(lista Inicio);
void EliminarPasaje(lista *Inicio, lista *Fin);
void ActualizarPasaje(lista *Inicio);
void EliminarListaPasaje(lista *Inicio, lista *Fin);
```

Creo el nodo pero no se si deba recorrer algo para que ingrese cada uno de los datos

```
nodo CrearNodo(void){
    system("cls");
    nodo nuevo; 
    int cod;
    char cli;
    nuevo = (nodo)malloc(sizeof(struct Pasajes));
    if(nuevo != NULL){
        printf("\n\t Ingreso de Pasajes\n");
        printf("\n Ingrese el codigo de su pasaje: "); scanf("%d", &cod);
        nuevo->codigo = cod;
        return nuevo;
    }else
        return NULL;
}
void InsertarPasaje(lista *Inicio, lista *Fin)
{
    nodo Nuevo=NULL, Aux=NULL;

    Nuevo = CrearNodo();

    if(Nuevo !=NULL)
    {   //lista vacia, se inserta primer elemento
        if(*Inicio == NULL)
        {
            *Inicio = Nuevo;
            (*Inicio)->ptrSig = NULL;
            *Fin = Nuevo;
        }
        else
        {   //lista no vacia, se inserta al final
            if(Nuevo->codigo > (*Fin)->codigo)
            {
                (*Fin)->ptrSig = Nuevo;
                Nuevo->ptrSig = NULL;
                *Fin = Nuevo;
            }
            //lista no vacia, se inserta al inicio
            else if((*Inicio)->codigo > Nuevo->codigo)
            {
                Nuevo->ptrSig = *Inicio;
                *Inicio = Nuevo;
            }
            //lista no vacia, se inserta en posicion intermedia
            else
            {
                Aux = *Inicio;
                while((Aux->ptrSig != NULL)&&(Aux->ptrSig->codigo <= Nuevo->codigo))
                {
                    Aux =Aux->ptrSig;
                }
                Nuevo->ptrSig = Aux->ptrSig;
                Aux->ptrSig = Nuevo;
            }
        }
    }else
    printf("\n\t No se puede insertar su pasaje");
}
```

En esta seccion quisiera saber como mostrar todos los elementos anteriormente mencionados

```
void RecorrerLista(lista Inicio)
{
    nodo Aux = NULL;
    if(Inicio !=NULL)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t Lista de pasajes\n");           
        Aux = Inicio;
        while(Aux !=NULL)
        {
            printf("\n Dato: %d", Aux->codigo);
            Aux = Aux->ptrSig;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\t La lista esta vacia");
    }
    printf("\n\n"); system("pause");
}
```